# ¿Cómo producir palabras aleatorias con un largo determinado?

Tags: python, lista, random

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente código

```
import random

vocals = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonats=['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n']

def generate_word(enterWord):
    word = ""
    while 0 <= enterWord:
            randconsonats = random.randint(0,15)
            randvocals = random.randint(0,4)
            word = word + consonats[randconsonats]
            word = word + vocals[randvocals]
            enterWord = enterWord - 1
    return word

def generate_list_word():
    enterList = int(input("Introduce la cantidad de palabras que quieres "))
    enterWord = int(input("Introduce el numero de caracteres "))
    list_Word  = []
    while 0 <= enterList:
        wordappend = generate_word(enterWord)
        list_Word.append(wordappend)
        enterList = enterList - 1
    return list_Word

generate_list_word()
```

Lo que quiero conseguir con el codigo es lo siguiente:

```
#Entrada:
#Numero de caracteres = 5
#Numero de palabras = 3
#Salida:
#sajet
#liwos
#jupaw
```

O sea, generar 3 palabras de 5 caracteres aleatorios cada una.

Lo he intentado hacer con este código, pero no me funciona. El problema que me da es el siguiente al ejecutarlo:

```
Introduce la cantidad de palabras que quieres 2
Introduce el numero de caracteres 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dam1\Desktop\Clases\Entornos de Desarrollo\ListViernes.py", line 26, in <module>
    generate_list_word()
  File "c:\Users\dam1\Desktop\Clases\Entornos de Desarrollo\ListViernes.py", line 21, in generate_list_word
    wordappend = generate_word(enterWord)
  File "c:\Users\dam1\Desktop\Clases\Entornos de Desarrollo\ListViernes.py", line 11, in generate_word
    word = word + consonats[randconsonats]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Creo que el error está al extraer de las listas los caracteres pero no estoy muy seguro.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anthonyx82 lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente.

```
import random
vocales=["a","e","i","o","u"]
consonantes=['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n']
def crear_palabras(cantidad_de_letras,cantidad_de_palabras):
    vocal=False
    lista_de_palabras=[]
    palabra_actual=""
    for i in range(cantidad_de_palabras):
        for i in range(cantidad_de_letras):
            if vocal == False:
                a=random.randint(0,len(consonantes)-1)
                palabra_actual+=consonantes[a]
                vocal=True
            else:
                a=random.randint(0,len(vocales)-1)
                palabra_actual+=vocales[a]
                vocal=False
        lista_de_palabras.append(palabra_actual)
        palabra_actual=""
    return lista_de_palabras
```

ahora llamas a la funcion de la siguiente manera.

```
palabras=crear_palabras(5,3)
for i in palabras:
    print(i)
```

el resultado es totalmente al azar,pero las vocales siempre estaran detras de las consonantes o viceversa
RESULTADO:

```
julof
dafuc
maman
```

Si te ayudo por favor valora esta pregunta tocando la flechita de la parte superior pliss :)
adios.

Answer (score 2):

La causa del error es que `consonants` tiene 11 elementos pero generas indices entre 0 y 14:

```
randconsonats = random.randint(0,15)
```

Lo más sano es siempre dejar que el software calcule:

```
randconsonats = random.randint(0,len(consonants))
```

Esto tiene varias ventajas:

1. Está claro la asociación entre la variable y la lista.
2. La variable siempre tendrá el valor correcto, sin importar los cambios a la lista.

#### Resolución Alternativa

Hay un método más fácil: forma una lista con todas las sílabas posibles y saca de ahí las partes de la palabras:

```
vocals = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonats=['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n']
silabas = [x+y for x in consonats for y in vocals]
```

con lo cual `silabas` contiene

```
['ba', 'be', 'bi', 'bo', 'bu', 'ca', 'ce', 'ci', 'co', 'cu', 'da', 'de', 'di', 'do', 'du', 'fa', 'fe', 'fi', 'fo', 'fu', 'ga', 'ge', 'gi', 'go', 'gu', 'ha', 'he', 'hi', 'ho', 'hu', 'ja', 'je', 'ji', 'jo', 'ju', 'ka', 'ke', 'ki', 'ko', 'ku', 'la', 'le', 'li', 'lo', 'lu', 'ma', 'me', 'mi', 'mo', 'mu', 'na', 'ne', 'ni', 'no', 'nu']
```

el resto es simplemente ir eligiendo al azar de esta lista y formando una palabra. Como puede ser que el largo pedido sea impar, al final simplemente recortamos el exceso:

```
numero = 3
letras = 5
for i in range(numero):
    palabra = ''.join(silabas[randint(0, len(silabas)-1)] for _ in range(letras // 2 + 1))[:letras]
```

Esto nos da palabra por palabra.

#### Demo

```
from random import randint

vocals = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonats=['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n']
silabas = [x+y for x in consonats for y in vocals]

print(silabas)
numero = 3
letras = 5
for i in range(numero):
    palabra = ''.join(silabas[randint(0, len(silabas)-1)] for _ in range(letras // 2 + 1))[:letras]
    print(palabra)
```

produce:

```
najil
nanif
denac

Process finished with exit code 0
```